# In my chatApp built on Kotlin,Firebase, i am getting a blank space message from receivers end as soon as i send a message

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I have made a chat app using firebase, kotlin and i was adding timestamps for new message that comes in. The timestamp is working fine, but  whenever a sender sends a message to a receiver, one blank space message immediately comes from receivers end.

This is my chatActivity.kt

```
class ChatActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private  lateinit var chatRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var messageBox: EditText
    private lateinit var sendButton : ImageView
    private  lateinit var messageAdapter: MessageAdapter
    private  lateinit var messageList : ArrayList<Message>
    private lateinit var mDbRef: DatabaseReference

    private val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss")

    var receiverRoom : String? = null
    var senderRoom : String ?= null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat)
        FirebaseService.sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("sharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    if (task.result != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(task.result)) {
                        val token: String = task.result!!
                        FirebaseService.token = token
                        val currentUserUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
                        val userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(currentUserUid.toString())
                        userRef.child("deviceToken").setValue(token)
                    }
                }
            }

        val name = intent.getStringExtra("name")
        //val sender_name = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.displayName
        val receiver_uid = intent.getStringExtra("uid")
        val sender_uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
        mDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        senderRoom =  receiver_uid + sender_uid
        receiverRoom =  sender_uid + receiver_uid

        supportActionBar?.title = name


        chatRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chatRecyclerView)
        messageBox =  findViewById(R.id.messagebox)
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.sendButton)
        messageList = ArrayList()
        messageAdapter = MessageAdapter(this, messageList)

        chatRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        chatRecyclerView.adapter = messageAdapter


        //adding data to recyclerview
        mDbRef.child("chats").child(senderRoom!!).child("messages")
            .addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                    messageList.clear()

                    for(postSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                        val message = postSnapshot.getValue(Message::class.java)
                        messageList.add(message!!)
                    }
                    messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    // AUTOSCROLL WHEN NEW MSG COMES
                    chatRecyclerView.getAdapter()?.let {
                        chatRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()?.smoothScrollToPosition(
                            chatRecyclerView,
                            RecyclerView.State(),
                            it.getItemCount()
                        )
                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                }

            })


        sendButton.setOnClickListener {

            val message = messageBox.text.toString()
            val currentTime = sdf.format(Date())
            val messageObject = Message(message, sender_uid,"",currentTime)
            if(message.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"you can't send empty message to "+name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                messageBox.setText("")
            }
            else{
                mDbRef.child("chats").child(senderRoom!!).child("messages").push()
                    .setValue(messageObject).addOnSuccessListener {

                            val messageRef =
                                mDbRef.child("chats").child(senderRoom!!).child("messages").push()

                            messageRef.ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :
                                ValueEventListener {
                                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                    val messageId =
                                        snapshot.key // get the ID of the newly added message


                                    mDbRef.child("chats").child(senderRoom!!).child("messages")
                                        .child(messageId!!)
                                        .child("timestamp").setValue(currentTime)


                                    mDbRef.child("chats").child(senderRoom!!).child("messages")
                                        .child(messageId!!)
                                        .child("delivery_status").setValue("delivered")


                                    mDbRef.child("chats").child(receiverRoom!!).child("messages")
                                        .push()
                                        .setValue(messageObject)
                                }

                                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                                    // handle error
                                }
                            })
                        }
                messageBox.setText("")
                // Get a reference to the current user's node in the database
                val currentUserUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
                val userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(
                    currentUserUid.toString()
                )

// Attach a listener to retrieve the user's name from the database
                userRef.child("name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                        // Retrieve the sender's name from the database
                        val senderName = snapshot.getValue(String::class.java)

                        // Use the sender's name to create the notification data object
                        val notificationData = NotificationData(senderName!!, message)
                        val receiverTokenRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(
                            receiver_uid.toString()
                        ).child("deviceToken")

                        receiverTokenRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                                val receiverToken = snapshot.getValue(String::class.java)

                                //FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(receiver_uid)
                                // Send the notification to the receiver's device token
                                PushNotification(notificationData, receiverToken!!).also {
                                    sendNotification(it)
                                }
                            }
                            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                                Log.w("ChatActivity", "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
                            }
                        })
                    }


                    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                        Log.w("ChatActivity", "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    private fun sendNotification(notification: PushNotification) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        try {
            val response = RetrofitInstance.api.postNotification(notification)
            if(response.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Response: ${Gson().toJson(response)}")
            } else {
                Log.e("TAG", response.errorBody()!!.string())
            }
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            Log.e("TAG", e.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to implement timestamps for every message but it happened with some empty text block from reciver's end

Comment: There's a lot of things that could be going wrong here, and from the amount of code you shared it is hard to say what specific is the cause. It's much more likely someone here can help if you take the time to create a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful). Failing that, debug the code on *your* system and tell us the results. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: If you're new to debugging an Android app, the Android docs have a great page on [debugging your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to get you started with, including the section on [working with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) and [inspecting varialbles](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: Thanks guys, I tried debugging it but couldn't find the issue then I figured out that the code is pretty ok and the real issue was with previous builds. Some of the previous builds added one extra "messages" node in the real-time database which was causing the issue. I deleted those nodes and rebuilt the project and it working fine now.
Also thanks @FrankvanPuffelen I will make sure to follow the points you shared before i ask questions.
Cheers!!

Comment: Good to hear you got it work @ANKITKUMAR 